# Stopping AppBar control showing on right click in WinJS

Tags: windows-store-apps, winjs, appbar

I'm trying to only show an [App Bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229670.aspx) when a user selects an item from a list view.  I've got the app bar showing by using the appBar.show() and appBar.hide() methods but its not the only time it can be shown.

When I right click the page and don't have anything selected, the app bar still shows.  How can I stop it showing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer this in my free ebook, [*Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript (2nd edition)*](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2), in the app bar section (page 480):

> Tip To prevent the app/nav bar from appearing, you can do one of two
>   things. First, to prevent an app bar or nav bar from appearing at all
>   (for any gesture), set the control’s disabled property to true.
>   Second, if you want to prevent it for, say, a right-click on a
>   particular element (such as a canvas), listen to the contextmenu
>   (right click) event for that element and call
>   eventArgs.preventDefault() within your handler.

Answer (score 0):

After much researching about, i found that the best option for myself was to allow the app bar to show naturally and show/hide the commands instead.

```
<div id="appBar"
     data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar"
     data-win-options="{placement:'bottom', layout:'commands'}">
    <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand"
            data-win-options="{id:'switchTradeDirection',
        type:'button',
        label:'Switch Direction',
        section:'selection'}"></button>
    <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand"
            data-win-options="{id:'secondary1',
        type:'button',
        label:'Secondary1',
        section:'selection'}"></button>
    <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand"
         data-win-options="{ id: 'list',
     extraClass:'multiSelect',
     type: 'content',
     label:'List',
     section: 'selection'}">
        <select class="options">
            <option>Option1</option>
            <option>Option2</option>
            <option>Option3</option>
            <option>Option4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

in the js file:

```
var appBarDiv = document.getElementById('appBar');
var appBar = appBarDiv.winControl;
if (selectedCount == 2) {
    appBar.showCommands(appBarDiv.querySelectorAll('.multiSelect'));
    appBar.sticky = true;
    appBar.show();
} else {
    appBar.hide();
    appBar.hideCommands(appBarDiv.querySelectorAll('.multiSelect'));
    appBar.sticky = false;
}
```